# Visual Studio: have to open with "Run as.." every time

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

When I click the VS 2010 icon to open it I get a popup box error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

I then need to right click the icon, click "Run as.." change "Current user" to "The Following user" then enter in my windows credentials and it opens fine.

This is happening suddenly (Windows XP) and I don't know why. It wasn't happening before and I haven't started logging in with a different user or anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you attach a debugger to it?

Comment: is your user an administrator?

Comment: Yes I am an admin of the machine

Comment: How exactly do I attach a debugger to it?

Comment: Start another copy, then click Tools, Attach To Process.

Comment: what process to attach to? devenv.exe hasn't started yet!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the VS settings for your logged-in user have become corrupted, causing VS to crash when it loads them.  Running as a different user uses that user's settings, so it works fine.

Try renaming `My Documents\Visual Studio 20xx\Settings` and see if that helps.

Also, try running VS with the `/SafeMode` option.

Comment: None of these suggestions worked. When I changed the setting folder name it warned me of this, said it will use a default, then continued and gave me the same error

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by a recently added extension.

Try [disabling all Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx), or running in [Safe Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293640.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could try starting Visual Studio while you have Process Monitor running -- if it's some sort of security error, you should see an error reading a file or reg key in there.  it's helped me with similar problems before.  You can find it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645